# How to find the function representing these points?

Tags: geometry, statistics, curves

I'm trying to find the function which satisfies these points in its domain and generalizes to the entire real line.

[image]

I have used interpolation but it won't generalize to new points. What are the other techniques that I can try?

Comment: Where do the points come from? Are they being generated by something? Do you notice any significant behaviour that might imply something about a suitable formula?

Comment: It looks like periodic. You can interpolate in one period and use periodic extension like $f(x)=g(x-T \cdot \lfloor x/T \rfloor)$, where $T$ is period and $g(x)$ is interpolation for one period. Also it looks like sum of several sines with various periods. Moreover, it looks very similar to $\sin(x)+\sin(2x)$.